# How to use two loop correctly in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, list, dictionary

Hi guys I have problem

This is my code :

```
services = {
    'first':[],
    'second':[]
}

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in services:
    print('loop-one -  ',i)
    for i in x:
        services['first'].append(i)

print(services)
```

Output of this code is `{'first': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'second': []}`
If you notice He added twice .

my purpose is something like this , I want add once
`{'first': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'second': []}`

Thanks !

Comment: Don't use `i` for both loops.

Comment: `for i in services` This defines the current item in `services` to the variable `i`, so your next variable should be named differently in the `for` loop: `for number in i`

Comment: it is very hard to tell what the actual problem is from this sample since you could just write `services['first'] = x` and get your desired output

Comment: @RyanHaining: Or `services['first'].extend(x)` to copy instead of aliasing (so if `x` or `services['first']` is changed later, the other one isn't affected).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here seems to be that in your outer loop you're iterating over the `services` dictionary. The `services` dictionary contains two key-value pairs to which you then iterate over the first key-value pair and append the result to the 'first' list key-value pair. May I ask why you don't just do something like this if your desired output is `{'first': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'second': []}?`

A simpler way to do it using a single for loop is like this you can find documentation on the extend method here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html:

```
for service in services:
    services[service].extend(x)
```

Is the requirement to have 2 loops? I am just wondering.

If so, you could try this syntax:

```
for service in services:
    print('loop-one -  ',service)
    for num in x:
        services[service].append(num)

print(services)
```

I am assuming you are trying to write the data from `x` array/list and then append that to the first and second lists. I hope this helps